# How to get all file list in my storage?

Tags: android, list, file

I'm making application that find specific file in my storage.
So I put all file list into List.

```
Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
searchFile(new File(Root));

void searchFile(File directory){
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        try{
            if(directory.exists()) {
                File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if(files[i].exists()) {
                        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                            File[] file = files[i].listFiles();
                            for (int j = 0; j < file.length; j++) {
                                searchFile(file[j].getPath());
                            }
                        } else
                            fileList.add(files[i].getPath());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

But My the number of all file is more than 60000.
So When I tried to debug, It worked so slowly.

How can I get All file list in my storage quickly?

Comment: Do away with the exists() function. Of course files and directories do exist if you can list them.

Comment: You call listFiles() three times in your function. You should do that only once.

Comment: The last listFiles() and following for loop are nonsense. If you have a directory you should immediately call the recursive searchFile().

Comment: The first listFiles() is nonsense too. You are not using the result.

Comment: I think this problem is cache file and folder. Because When I search the specific word like 'do', It was searched every file including cache file like '84637828ebc3dkjk394h3jk23jhdohjkskek23'. How I can exclude the cache file using listFiles()?

Comment: ¿?????? Please dont change the subject. First react to the suggestions we did.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
searchFile(new File(Root));

void searchFile(File directory){
        try{
            if(directory.exists()) {
                File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                for (File file : files) {
                    if(file.exists()) {
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            File[] innerFiles = file.listFiles();
                            for (File innerFile : innerFiles) {
                                searchFile(innerile.getPath());
                            }
                        } else
                            fileList.add(file.getPath());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

This will narrow down your performance issue to a certain level.